# Preprocessed FileIO generator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, file-io, generator

My script uses `pandas.read_csv` to directly read read csv files into data frames. A user is supposed to provide a configuration file that contains labels of columns to retain along with corresponding data types. Let me illustrate with an example. Here is a csv.

```
factor,value1,value2,value3
a,1,2.0,1
b,3,4.1,2
c,5,6.2,3
```

A config file would be

```
factor char
value1 integer
value2 float
```

I have a function that transforms the config into a dictionary

```
col_types = read_types(config)  # -> {"factor": str, "value1": numpy.int32, "value2": numpy.float64}
```

Then I read the csv

```
df = pandas.read_csv(csv_file, header=0, sep=",", index_col=False, dtype=col_types)
```

Sometimes labels listed in a configuration file do not match those in a csv file in terms of letter case consistence, e.g. it can be `value1` in the config file and `Value1` in the csv. Hence I want to be able to get a `FileIO` stream that automatically converts lines into lowercase. I tried this

```
def read_df(...):
    with open(csv_file) as csv:
        lower_lines = (line.lower() for line in csv)
        return pandas.read_csv(lower_lines, header=0, sep=",", 
                               index_col=False, dtype=col_types)
```

This fails, because `pandas.read_csv` requires a file path or a FileIO stream, not a generator.

Then I attempted to use `DataFrame.from_records` that can read generators, but doesn't have the `dtype` argument of `pandas.read_csv`. Finally I ended up mimicking a file with my own class

```
class GeneratorWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, generator):
        """
        :type generator: Generator[str]
        """
        self._generator = generator

    def read(self, n=0):
        return next(self._generator, "")

def read_df(...):
    with open(csv_file) as csv:
        lower_lines = GeneratorWrapper((line.lower() for line in csv))
        return pandas.read_csv(lower_lines, header=0, sep=",", 
                               index_col=False, dtype=col_types)
```

This thing works, but I think it's sort of an overkill. I believe there should be something more Pythonic to get a preprocessed FileIO stream. To make it short, is there a better way to get a lazily processed FileIO-like stream in Python?

**Note.**

I know that I can read in all lines, process them and pass to `pandas.DataFrame`, but I don't want to use any intermediate Python containers, because the files are huge and I don't want to run into memory errors.